# Magento - using Solr search engine, layered navigation on search results page shows wrong filter counts

Tags: php, oop, magento, solr

I changed the Catalog Search engine in Magento to use Apache Solr, which works fine (after some tweaking to existing extensions).

However, the "layered navigation" (also called "faceting" or "search filters") on the left-hand-side of the Search Results page is displaying the wrong number of product counts for each category.

Example: if I do a search which returns only 10 results, the results themselves are fine, but I'm the filters show a count of HUNDREDS of products instead of 10 or less, i.e. presumably all the products in my catalogue.

I am using the extension "Amasty Shop By" which affects the filters, but having walked through the code, as far as I can see it's getting its filter items from normal Magento functions:

```
class Amasty_Shopby_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
    // Code removed ...

    public function getItemsAsArray()
    {
        $items = array(); 

        // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ Right here ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
        foreach (parent::getItems() as $itemObject) {

        // Code removed ...

        }
    }
}
```

I'm talking about these counts, here, in red:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Magento Enterprise?

Amasty Shopby module does not support Solr, they do have a planned release to support Solr but not yet.

I am currently working on the same issue, but am having an issue indexing multiselect attributes.

I will let you know if you are still interested if I come up with a solution

Comment: Please, that would be awesome. I did solve it by messing around in `Model/Resource/Collection.php` but I can't remember any details of what I did that fixed it!